# Unexpected alert open: {Alert text : } laravel dusk

Tags: php, laravel-5, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I am creating some dusk tests and some times i get `unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }` error on some of the tests. On my local tests pass some times and some time throw this error. I am not sure what's causing this issue as there are no alerts in my pages, as `Alert text is also empty`. And i don't see any alerts in the page while running tests in UI mode.

Following is the complete information of the error on my local

```
1) Tests\Browser\contacts\CreateContactTest::testCreate
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpenException: unexpected 
alert open: {Alert text : }
(Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 
(8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64)
```

And also, same error is thrown in my `CircleCI` tests as well, following is the information on CircleCI2

```
1) Tests\Browser\auth\RegisterTest::testRegister
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpenException: unexpected 
alert open: {Alert text : }
(Session info: headless chrome=63.0.3239.132)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 
(47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.4.0-111-generic x86_64)
```

What could have caused such issues, keeping in mind i don't have any alerts open in the code and tests some times succeed as well. `Can this be any chrome driver issue ?`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with WordPress, I tried different solutions but they don't work. I assume this alert is generated not by the website, but rather by headless chrome. I am using Docksal development environment and selenium/standalone-chrome image.

Comment: Same problem here, I have a total of 3 tests, each one of them passes but when i'm running all 3 together it fails with this Exception.

Comment: Has anyone found a way around this? I get this sometimes too, which breaks our build unnecessarily. I've not been able to reproduce this in UI mode, nor have I been able to headless on my local environment. It seems to only happen on Codeship. Which uses the linux driver (locally it's the mac driver)

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me because I had an `onbeforeunload` handler registered on the page that reminds users that they have unsaved work.
When the test is finished, the browser will "close" the page, leading to this alert / dialog popping up.

I fixed it by explicitly triggering this event and accepting the dialog at the end of the test case:

```
$browser->visit('about:blank')->waitForDialog()->acceptDialog();
```